# Is it possible to use multiple interfaces on one variable?

Tags: typescript

Lets say I have a variable:

```
var product:Product;
```

the var product uses the Product interface, but I want to add a generic property 'hide' to know in my view if the product needs to be hidden.  I could add 'hide' to the Product interface, but it's not a property of the Product model so it doesnt feel right.

I could make a special interface that extends Product to have both properties, but i'm wondering if there's a more simpel way to do this, something like:

```
var product:Product & Hide;
```

Is there such a syntax?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly right and it's called [Intersection Types.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types)

So either:

```
interface Hidden {
    hide: boolean;
}

let product: Product & Hidden;
```

Or

```
let product: Product & { hide: boolean }
```

Comment: Thanks! My IDE shows an error, but tslint doesn't, so I guess I need to update/switch my IDE

Comment: Which IDE is that? What's the error? What's the version of typescript that your IDE uses?

Comment: I use phpstorm, but to be honest, I have no idea what typescript it uses. The error: it expects a statement, so my guess is it doesn't know about intersection types. For now, I'm already satisfied by your original answer, but if you have a solution for the IDE error, please let me know ;)

Comment: Go to the settings of phpstorm, then Languages & Frameworks > TypeScript. There you should see "TypeScript version".

Comment: It seems the compiler is not enabled (should it?). If I would enable it, the compiler version would be v1.4

Comment: Oh wow. Then yeah, enable it, and use a more recent version, if not 2.x then at least 1.8.x.  You can install it using npm and then set it up there instead of it using the bundle typescript